# Date and Time in Spark Timestamp format - how to calculate difference?

Tags: sql, apache-spark

Assume I don't have access to the underlying code that's producing the table. And that I'm relatively new to this.

The timestamp column has the format of "2021-08-26T11:14:08.251Z" which looks to be a spark timestamp format - but I'm not sure if it's in that datatype or a string.

I need to calculate the difference between two timestamp columns that are in the above format - how do I turn what you see there, into something that I can run a difference calculation on in a SQL query? And not in any underlying pyspark code?

Would love if you could give me two answers one if it's in the native timestamp datatype and one if it's actually just a string!

Comment: Difference between two timestamp columns in terms of what timeframe? like days,minutes,seconds,hours

Comment: doesn't matter because I can convert it - but let's say seconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spark `timestamp type` accepts only **`yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS`**

To get difference between two timestamps as shown below example.

**Example:**

```
df.show()
//+------------------------+-----------------------+
//|ts                      |ts1                    |
//+------------------------+-----------------------+
//|2021-08-26T11:14:08.251Z|2021-08-25 11:14:08.251|
//+------------------------+-----------------------+
df.select(unix_timestamp(to_timestamp(col("ts"))).as("ts"),unix_timestamp(to_timestamp(col("ts1"))).as("ts1")).
withColumn("diff",col("ts1")-col("ts")).show(false)
//+----------+----------+------+
//|ts        |ts1       |diff  |
//+----------+----------+------+
//|1629976448|1629915248|-61200|
//+----------+----------+------+
```

---

**`Update:`**

```
df.createOrReplaceTempView("tmp"

spark.sql("select ts,ts1,ts-ts1 as diff from (select unix_timestamp(to_timestamp(ts)) as ts,unix_timestamp(to_timestamp(ts1)) as ts1 from tmp)e").show(10,false)
//+----------+----------+-----+
//|ts        |ts1       |diff |
//+----------+----------+-----+
//|1629976448|1629915248|61200|
//+----------+----------+-----+
```

Comment: Can that be used in a SQL Select statement though? I can't seem to get it to work.

Comment: @DataDrivesEverything  absolutely we can do it, check my updated answer!

Comment: Okay - yeah so basically just...

SELECT ts
, ts1
, (unix_timestamp(to_timestamp(ts))- (unix_timestamp(to_timestamp(ts1)) as diff
FROM table
WHERE X
AND Y

That's what I needed thanks!